# In order traversal error?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree, inorder

Having some trouble with this recursive in order traversal method
My code is supposed to inorder traverse a given tree and return true if it did it correctly. I do this by traversing it and adding the elements to an arrayList. I have a method isSorted which returns 1 if the array list is sorted (which is done every time i add an array list element) and 0 if it isn't.

It does the job of returning the correcy 1 or 0 corresponding to if it is sorted or not but it doesn't cease execution after that. Because if it isnt sorted than it is safe to say the in order traversal wasnt done correctly but it says it was. Can anyone help?

```
 public ArrayList<Integer> inOrderCheck = new ArrayList<Integer>();


boolean checkBST(Node root) {

   if(root != null){
       checkBST(root.left);
       if(addToList(root.data) == 0){
           return false;
       }

       checkBST(root.right);

   }


    return true;

   // Integer[] inOrderArray = inOrderCheck.toArray(new Integer[inOrderCheck.size()]);




}

int addToList(int data){

    //System.out.println("Initial size of inOrderCheck: " + inOrderCheck.size());
if(!(inOrderCheck.contains(data))){
   // System.out.println("Adding: " + data);
      inOrderCheck.add(data);
}

//System.out.println(" size of inOrderCheck after adddition: " + inOrderCheck.size());
   // System.out.println("Contents of inOrderCheck: " + inOrderCheck);   

  //  System.out.println("Result of isSorted: " + isSorted());   

return isSorted();    
}



int isSorted(){

int sorted = 0;        
for (int i = 1; i < inOrderCheck.size(); i++) {
     //System.out.println("Result of isSorted: " + inOrderCheck.get(i-1) + " "+ inOrderCheck.get(i));   
    if (inOrderCheck.get(i-1) < (inOrderCheck.get(i)) ) {
        sorted = 1;
    }else
        sorted = 0;
}

return sorted;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't ignore the boolean returned from the recursive calls to `checkBST`.

Comment: @Eran like what setting them equal to a boolean?

Comment: @SJackson193 If `checkBST(root.left)` returns false, you should return false. Same for `checkBST(root.right)`.

Answer (score 2):

You are ignoring the values returned by the recursive calls. If the either of the calls for the left or right sub-tree return false, you should return false.

```
boolean checkBST(Node root) {
    if (root != null) {
        if (!checkBST(root.left))
            return false;
        if (!addToList(root.data))
            return false;
        if (!checkBST(root.right))
            return false;
    }   
    return true;
}
```

Besides, your `isSorted` method has some issues.
First of all, it should return boolean. Second of all, it shouldn't return `0` when the list contains just one element.

I'd change it to:

```
boolean isSorted() {     
    for (int i = 1; i < inOrderCheck.size(); i++) { 
        if (inOrderCheck.get(i-1) >= inOrderCheck.get(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

boolean addToList(int data) {
    if(!inOrderCheck.contains(data)) {
        inOrderCheck.add(data);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return isSorted();
}
```

Comment: i did that and now it has a problem adding things

Comment: like lets say it goes to a leaf node. it just stops there and never goes back to check on the root

Comment: @SJackson193 It would stop adding elements to the list if the last added element causes the list to become not-sorted, which means the tree is not a BST.

Comment: it seems to literally only add the smallest element then it just stops

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 16 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31    Like this list should keep adding until it gets to 16 and then realizes there is a duplicate then return false, my code just adds 1 and stios

Comment: its weird its literally just adding one to the list

Comment: so basically its just returning false for everything

Comment: @SJackson193 Your `isSorted` method is wrong when the list has only one element. You should change `int sorted = 0` to `int sorted = 1;`